# I got error Internal or external command error by command prompt only, but it is fine in anaconda prompt. Why?

Tags: anaconda, command-prompt

If I want to open a jupyter notebook by command prompt I got below error:

```
'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

operable program or batch file.

And also, I want to use pip commands, I got the same error:

```
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

But in anaconda prompt I did not get any error it is run finely. I can open jupyter notebook without any error and also I can run pip without any error to install packages.

What can I do for command prompt to overcome this error?

Comment: Please search this site for *is not recognized as an internal or external command*. This question has been asked and answered here literally dozens (if not hundreds) of times. The very first thing you should do before you even think about asking a question is to do a basic search.

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda Prompt adds the path to the Anaconda binaries (jupiter, pip, etc.) to the PATH environment variable, so you can run them as commands from the prompt.

To be able to run the commands from the "normal" prompt you can manually add the path to the corresponding binaries to the PATH environment variable. Or choose the corresponding option while installing Anaconda (see Step 8 in the [installation instructions](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/windows/)).

Note the recommendation in the docs:

> We do not recommend adding Anaconda to to the PATH environment variable, since this can interfere with other software. Instead, use Anaconda software by opening Anaconda Navigator or the Anaconda Prompt from the Start Menu.